# Erratic behavior of S3 Bucket - blames CORS file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using a javascript request to get files from an S3 bucket, and I, for seemingly no reason get this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/rifff_bucket/uploads%2F20130313T2336Z_5a9d96ef0d43ef775b9781cd336e1eb2%2Fsnarelayer.mp3. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I can always get to this file by simply putting the URL in the browser - it exists, and works. Other similar files in the bucket, using the same javascript request, work.

Although it seems to be blaming the CORS configuration this always happens, even when there is no CORS file at all. Even though other similar files continue to work with no CORS file.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Unclear which change to my CORS file did it - if any.

Point to note is that, unless I really am going mad, browsers seem to cache the rejection. So if you make a change to the CORS file etc. you need to clear cache to see what effect it had. This is the cause of the "Erratic Behavior".

Comment: Would you mind accepting your answer, since it fixed the issue?